# Cannot install deepin screen recorder on my kde neon installation

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I cannot install Deepin screen recorder on my KDE neon install. Seems there are some dependencies that `apt` refuses to install. `apt --fix-broken install` doesn't solve the issue.

I tried installing some of these dependencies manually but the I am led to even more dependencies to them that I still cannot install.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 < none -> 5.0.0-1build2 @un puN Ib >
Broken deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 Depends on libdtkwidget2:amd64 < none | 2.1.1-1build3 @un uH > (>= 2.0.11)
  Considering libdtkwidget2:amd64 0 as a solution to deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated libstartup-notification0:amd64
    Reinst Failed early because of qtbase-abi-5-12-8:amd64
Investigating (0) deepin-notifications:amd64 < none -> 3.3.4-1build1 @un uN Ib >
Broken deepin-notifications:amd64 Depends on libdtkwidget2:amd64 < none | 2.1.1-1build3 @un uH > (>= 2.0.11)
  Considering libdtkwidget2:amd64 0 as a solution to deepin-notifications:amd64 0
  Holding Back deepin-notifications:amd64 rather than change libdtkwidget2:amd64
Investigating (1) deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 < none -> 5.0.0-1build2 @un puN Ib >
Broken deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 Depends on deepin-notifications:amd64 < none | 3.3.4-1build1 @un uH >
  Considering deepin-notifications:amd64 0 as a solution to deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed because of libdtkwidget2:amd64
Broken deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 Depends on libdtkwidget2:amd64 < none | 2.1.1-1build3 @un uH > (>= 2.0.11)
  Considering libdtkwidget2:amd64 0 as a solution to deepin-screen-recorder:amd64 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 deepin-screen-recorder : Depends: deepin-notifications but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libdtkwidget2 (>= 2.0.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message! Don't post logvomit.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 deepin-screen-recorder : Depends: deepin-notifications but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libdtkwidget2 (>= 2.0.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The "depends on" relationship is a requirement. If you want can try to install the dependencies (and their dependencies (and their dependencies ( ... ))), you might get it work. Ubuntu isn't `deepin` and doesn't provide the same services or library versions that `deepin` does.